# React TypeScript HoC - passing Component as the prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

Following this tutorial: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow.

Trying to reproduce the code:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/login",
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);
```

In TypeScript:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Route, RouterProps } from 'react-router';

interface Props extends RouterProps {
  component: React.Component;
}

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: Props) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => <Component {...props} />}
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

But it would always fail. Tried different variations. The one I've posted the most recent one. Getting:

[image]

It seems to me that I have to pass Generic for the Component type, but I don't know how.

**EDIT:**

The closest solution so far:

```
interface Props extends RouteProps {
  component: () => any;
}

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: Props) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => <Component {...props} />}
    />
  );
};
```

And then:

```
<PrivateRoute component={Foo} path="/foo" />
```

Answer (score 41):

You want to pass a component constructor, not a component instance:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Route, RouteProps } from 'react-router';

interface Props extends RouteProps {
    component: React.ComponentType;
}

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: Props) => {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => <Component {...props} />}
        />
    );
};

export default PrivateRoute;

class Foo extends React.Component {

}
let r = <PrivateRoute component={Foo} path="/foo" />
```

**Edit**

A more complete solution should be generic and use `RouteProps` instead `RouterProps`:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Route, RouteProps } from 'react-router';

type Props<P> =  RouteProps & P & {
    component: React.ComponentType<P>;
}

const PrivateRoute = function <P>(p: Props<P>) {
    // We can't use destructuring syntax, because : "Rest types may only be created from object types", so we do it manually.
    let rest = omit(p, "component");
    let Component = p.component;
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props: P) => <p.component {...props} />}
        />
    );
};

// Helpers
type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = ({[P in T]: P } & {[P in U]: never } & { [x: string]: never })[T];  
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Diff<keyof T, K>>; 
function omit<T, TKey extends keyof T>(value:T, ... toRemove: TKey[]): Omit<T, TKey>{
    var result = Object.assign({}, value);
    for(let key of toRemove){
        delete result[key];
    }
    return result;
}


export default PrivateRoute;

class Foo extends React.Component<{ prop: number }>{

}
let r = <PrivateRoute component={Foo} path="/foo" prop={10} />
```

Comment: This seems like move towards right direction. However not sure how to use `PrivateRoute` in this case. Smth like `<PrivateRoute component={Foo} path="/foo" />` gives properties mismatch error. So either one has use smth different from `React.Component` or provide different `props` when using `PrivateRoute`.

Comment: @Oleg updated the solution to be generic and corrected usage of `RouterProps` to `RouteProps`

Comment: Thank you for putting time into this and extended answer. However this seems to be an overkill. I have updated description with the closest to the goal code. Now the task is to find correct signature for the `component`. According to https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js#L19 - it is just a func. Debugger pointed it as `() => Element`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: @Oleg If the generic version is overkill (I don't necessarily think it is since you will be reusing it but it's your call)  why doesn't the first solution work ? I included the full code for it, it compiles for me. Do you have with an issue with it ?

Answer (score 6):

After a few hours and some investigation, here is the solution that fits my requirements:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Route, RouteComponentProps, RouteProps } from 'react-router';

const PrivateRoute: React.SFC<RouteProps> =
  ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    if (!Component) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={(props: RouteComponentProps<{}>) => <Component {...props} />}
      />
    );
  };

export default PrivateRoute;
```

---

- No `any`;
- No extra complexity;
- Composition pattern retained;

Comment: I think you meant `export default PrivateRoute;` in your final line