# How can I require a ref for child component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-forwardref

I'm trying to create a React component which accepts a `children` prop. In order to function properly, `children` must be able to take a ref. That works fine if they are built-in React components, but if I pass in any custom component (either my own or from a library), there's a risk that the component cannot take a ref, breaking functionality.

```
const MyComponent = ({ children }: { children: WhatShouldThisBe }) => {
  // Passing the child onto a component from a library that expects to be able to pass it a ref
  return (
    <WrapperWhichExpectsChildToHaveRef>
      {children}
    </WrapperWhichExpectsChildToHaveRef>
  );
}

// Works
<MyComponent><div>Hello</div></MyComponent>

// Doesn't work, and should throw a type error
const NoForwardedRef = () => <div>Hello</div>
<MyComponent><NoForwardedRef /><MyComponent>
```

Functional components in React by default cannot take refs, so I couldn't pass a functional component in as a child, and have it work. Ideally, I'd like to require on a type level that only children which can receive refs are allowed, so that this is immediately apparent when using a "bad" component.

Is there a way to declare that the `children` prop must take a ref? In other words, is there some sort of type that is, essentially, `ReactComponentWhichTakesRef`? Searched around for answers (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56378639/typescript-react-enforce-correct-ref-props)), but surprisingly haven't found anything that fits this scenario.

Comment: This actually depends on the use case, do you want to access the children as HTMLElement or as JSX element. With HTMLElement, you can set/get the HTML properties. In case you just want to render the child inside your component then JSX element would be better approach.

Comment: We don't need to get/set HTML properties, so JSX would be better, I think

Comment: Then https://stackoverflow.com/a/49274255/5309486 solution might work for you.

Comment: So you mean, to pass in a constructor for a component, rather than a component? Is there no other way to do this? (eg, no prop for JSXElementWhichTakesARef?) It seems like a way worse interface to require a constructor in place of a rendered component.